# dont show columns which value is 0 anychart

Tags: anychart, anychart-8.2

[image]

In above image you can see 'Rel 02' skipped, because value is 0 (zero) in 2016 similarly Rel 08 also.

Same the way, how to skip in anychart ?

Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AnyChart library always shows all declared points (X, categories) even if the value is zero/null/undefined. You can avoid this behavior only by removing this point from your dataset in preprocessing.

Comment: If i remove the point from dataset like below
chartData = {header: ['#', 'poduction', 'Rel 02', 'Rel 04', 'Rel 06', 'Rel 08','Rel 10'],
rows: [['2016', 1,,1,,2,1],['2017', 18, 5, 1, 2,2,3]]};
then empty space is coming, i dont want space also.
For example in above image, under 2016 it's not showing Rel 02 but in our anychart it's coming as one empty space.

Comment: You can implement such chart like this - https://playground.anychart.com/w2oY471b

Comment: Its great support from you, few more small fixes need. 
1) between years we have separator with | symbol, but this | coming below of years not like you. for you its coming beside of the years. even if i increase value in below line, it increasing to down direction
additionalXaxis.ticks()
            .length(100)
            .position('inside');
2) In above image years showing at top, is it possible in anychart?

Comment: And tool-tip also need to modify, 
tool-tip heading showing with numbers like 1,2,3, etc.. don't want this and need to show x-axis and y-axis title in tool-tip one after other.

Comment: I've added spaces between bars, placed x-axis (with years) at the top, formatted tooltip. Here is a modified sample - https://playground.anychart.com/YoNuaQkb